# Vanilla Javascript: How do I create a working searchbar with hidden results?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keycode, search-box

I am pretty new to Javascript and have been using it for almost a month. I am trying to create a website easter egg that can be found by typing a hidden word into the searchbar. My problem mostly has to do with making the variable **value** read the strings in the **array**. There were no error messages that popped up.

Here is my code:

```
let searchResults = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird'];
let searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-box .input-box #searchbar');

function searchBar() {
  searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    } else {
    }
    });
  searchInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (value == searchResults[2] && (event.keyCode == 13)) {
      window.location.href = "bird.html";
    } else {
    }
  });
}
```

There is also a small additional issue with the keycode firing off multiple times. I'm not too worried about this, but it would be nice to find a solution for it.

Comment: It's firing more than once because you're calling `searchBar()` more than once. Every time that is called you're adding a new duplicate event listener.

Comment: On top of @Iwrestledabearonce.'s comment. It is a typical javascript memory leak. You bind a new event listener every time you can `searchBar()`.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I don't see where the OP is calling `searchBar()` in the code, so how do you know it's called multiple times?

Comment: I had searchbar() in my html and was using onKeyPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "keyCode" property for an input event. The keyCode exists only on [`keyboard events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), but [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) is it's own, separate type of event.

Use the keyup event instead. There's really no reason to have two separate event handlers anyway.

```js
let searchResults = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird'];
let searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchbar');


searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    
    let value = event.target.value;
    if(value == searchResults[2]){
    
      // window.location.href = "bird.html";
      console.log("birb");
    
    }else{
    
      // User hit enter but it wasn't bird...
    }
    
  }
});
```

```html
<input id=searchbar>
```